# What is the best approach and optimal path to create sbt multi-module project with activator?

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-module, typesafe-activator

I am creating my projects with simple 'activator new '. Now i wanted to create a multimodule project to split for instance frontend logic, backend logic. What is the best way to create multimodule project with activator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activator is just an enhanced sbt, thus you can freely follow the sbt instruction: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html

In short you have to put your activator project in subdirectories and define dependency in the root build.sbt

Answer (score 1):

There is a multi-module project template here: https://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/ScalaQualityCodeMultiprojectSeed